# Better way to use UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table products that have 5 fields to supplier

code            supplier_1     supplier_2     supplier_3
000001          3              87             25
000002          12             5              48

I have to bring the code of product and all suppliers that have relation with
For that i create a query of each supplier and relate then
like

```
select code supplier1
from products
union
select code supplier2
from products
... and so on
```

there is another way to do that ?

Comment: The better way is to not model your table like that. Have multiple rows for code `000001` instead of multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Starting in MySQL 8.0.14, you can use a lateral join:

```
select t.code, s.supplier
from t cross join lateral
     (select supplier_1 as supplier union all
      select supplier_2 as supplier union all
      select supplier_3 as supplier union all
      select supplier_4 as supplier 
     ) s;
```